# Kotlin - List of items to item of lists

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

I have a list of objects that I want to convert to an object of lists of following type

```
data class Value(val x : Int, val y: Int)
```

to an object of the following type:

```
data class Collection(val xs : List<Int>, val ys: List<Int>)
```

What I'm looking for is something similar to the `collect` operator in RxJava or a better way of doing this if possible. Any one have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to use separate `map` calls to get `xs` and `ys` from your `Value`s:

```
fun collectionOf(values: List<Value>) = 
    Collection(values.map { it.x }, 
               values.map { it.y })
```

Usage example:

```
val values = listOf(Value(1, 2), Value(3, 4))
val collection = collectionOf(values) // Collection(xs=[1, 3], ys=[2, 4])
```

If you want to do it in a single iteration over the `Value`s, you can use simple `for` loop:

```
fun collectionOf(values: List<Value>) {
    val xs = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val ys = mutableListOf<Int>()

    for ((x, y) in values) {
        xs.add(x)
        ys.add(y)
    }

    return Collection(xs, ys)
}
```

Since `Collection` contains read-only lists, I don't see a simpler way to construct it than to make the lists first, of course, not considering expressive yet inefficient functional solutions like this one, which copies `xs` and `ys` on each iteration:

```
fun collectionOf(values: List<Value>) = 
    values.fold(Collection(listOf(), listOf())) { acc, it -> 
        Collection(acc.xs + it.x, acc.ys + it.y) 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran all three and the map method takes the least amount of time for 100000 item list. I'll put up the runnable code in a separate answer for people to test out if they choose.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a collector would be a [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html)

```
val values = listOf(Value(1,2), Value(3,4), Value(5,6))

val collection = 
    values.fold(Collection(listOf(), listOf()))
    { acum, value ->  Collection(acum.xs + value.x, acum.ys + value.y)}

println(collection) // => Collection(xs=[1, 3, 5], ys=[2, 4, 6])
```

But for this particular case is simpler to just map each position of the touple.

```
val collection2 = Collection(values.map(Value::x), values.map(Value::y))
println(collection2) // => Collection(xs=[1, 3, 5], ys=[2, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran all the methods provided in @hotkey's answer and the map method is the fastest. Following is the code I ran:

```
data class Value(val x : Int, val y: Int)
data class Collection(val xs : List<Int>, val ys: List<Int>)
fun collectionOf(values: List<Value>): Collection {
    val xs = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val ys = mutableListOf<Int>()

    for ((x, y) in values) {
        xs.add(x)
        ys.add(y)
    }

    return Collection(xs, ys)
}
var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
(1..100000).map { Value(it * 1, it * 3) }.fold(Collection(listOf(), listOf()), { acc, value -> Collection(acc.xs + value.x, acc.ys + value.y) })
println("Fold takes: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
(1..100000).map { Value(it * 1, it * 3) }.let { Collection(it.map { it.x }, it.map { it.y }) }
println("\nMap takes: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
collectionOf((1..100000).map { Value(it * 1, it * 3) })
println("\nCollection takes: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime))
```

Sample output is:

```
Fold takes: 12776
Map takes: 12
Collection takes: 29
```